# Parse file, find a string and store next values

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, file, parsing

I need to parse a file according to different rules.
The file contains several lines. 
I go through the file line by line. When I find a specific string, I have to store the data present in the next lines until a specific character is found.

Example of file:

```
start {
  /* add comment */
  first_step {
     sub_first_step {
     };
     sub_second_step {
        code = 50,
        post = xxx (aaaaaa,
                    bbbbbb,
                    cccccc,
                    eeeeee),
        number = yyyy (fffffff,
                       gggggg,
                       jjjjjjj,
                       ppppppp),
     };
```

So, in this case:

```
 File.open(@file_to_convert, "r").each_line do |line|
```

In "line" I have my current line. I need to:

1) find when the line contains the string "xxx"

```
if line.include?("union") then
```

Correct?

2) store the next values (e.g.: aaaa, bbbb, ccccc,eeee) in an array until I find the character ")". This highlights that the section is finished.
I think we I reach the line with the string "xxxx" I have to iterate the next lines inside the block "if".

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing `if line.include?("union") then ` to check if the line contains the string `"xxx"`.

Comment: because I'm quite new with ruby so this was my first idea. But any other method is welcome!!!

Comment: After that  I have found the string "xxxx", I have to store the values until I find the character ")". I can use this character to terminate the iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
file_contents = File.read(@file_to_convert)

lines = file_contents[/xxx \(([^)]+)\)/, 1].split
# => ["aaaaaa,", "bbbbbb,", "cccccc,", "eeeeee"]
```

The regex (`xxx \(([^)]+)\)`) takes all the text after `xxx (` until the next `)`, and `split` splits it into its items.

Answer (score 0):

It think this is what you are looking for:

```
looking = true
results = []
File.open(@file_to_convert, "r").each_line do |line|
  if looking
    if line.include?("xxx")
      looking = false
      results << line.scan(/\(([^,]*)/x)
    end
  else
    if line.include?(")")
      results << line.strip.delete('),')
      break
    else
      results << line.strip.delete(',')
    end
  end
end
puts results
```